# Getting form data from vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to make a edit form thats pre-populated by my vuex model.

My idea was to bind the input to `data`, and populate `data` from the computed vuex getters.

Then when the user is done filling out the form, submit `data` to vuex and the server.

The problem is on load, data is empty so the template errors out.

> Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of
>   undefined"

*(simplified)*

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model= "title" >
</template>

<script>      
  ...mapGetters('project', {
    projectById: 'byId',
  }),
  data: function(){
    return {
      title: this.project.title
    }
  }

  computed: {
    project() {
      var project = this.projectById(Number.parseInt(this.id))
      return (project === undefined) ? {} : project;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you add content of the error to the question?

Comment: Added.  It's just undefined initially because project hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: You cannot reference a computed value in the data function. When the component is instantiated, the data function is called *before* computed properties are added to the component, so it will always be undefined.

Comment: Try this code inside `data()`: `project: ...this.projectById(Number.parseInt(this.id))`

Comment: Try using a computed property for `title` property as well. Generally you should prefer computed properties if a computation is involved for getting a property, like your case.